# Disable cursor changing to SizeWE for some items in Win32 header

Tags: winapi, header, cursor, mouseenter

I need to prevent resizing of some items in a Win32 header control. No problem to process the HDN_BEGINTRACK notification message and cancel it - the problem is in the cursor indicating that the item can be resized. For instance, if the first item can't be resized, I see this:

[image]

, but I'd prefer to see this:

[image]

I can ignore the cursor change by suppressing the WM_SETCURSOR message, but the problem is how to know the header item WM_SETCURSOR is generated for. I can detect the item under the mouse pointer in WM_MOUSEMOVE using the HDM_HITTEST message, but WM_MOUSEMOVE is sent to window procedure only after WM_SETCURSOR. I analyzed all notification messages for the Win32 header control, and it seems, it does not have an equivalent of the MouseEnter event that is sent to the window procedure before WM_SETCURSOR.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sub-class the header control if you haven't already.

In the sub-class, intercept the `WM_SETCURSOR` message, and use `GetMessagePos()` to get the coordinates of the mouse. These are in screen coordinates, so you need to convert them to client coordinates for the header control hit test.

```
// in the window sub-class
if (uMsg == WM_SETCURSOR)
{
    DWORD dwPos = GetMessagePos();
    HDHITTESTINFO hti;
    hti.pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(dwPos);
    hti.pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(dwPos);
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &hti.pt);
    SendMessage(hWnd, HDM_HITTEST, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&hti));

    if (...) // test for items we want to block
    {
        SetCursor(LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW));
        return TRUE;
    }

    // pass through to regular WndProc
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of this ;). Sure, I already subclassed the control and as I wrote, and I process both WM_SETCURSOR and WM_MOUSEMOVE. I use almost the same code in WM_MOUSEMOVE to know what item is under the cursor (something like MouseEnter/MouseLeave), and as I see after your answer, this functionality will be duplicated in WM_SETCURSOR. What do you think, can I determine the current hot item only in WM_SETCURSOR and use this info in WM_MOUSEMOVE?

Comment: And my tests show that there is no need to use `SetCursor(LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW))` in this code snippet. If you return TRUE, the cursor remains the standard IDC_ARROW and there is no need to set it explicitly.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), WM_SETCURSOR provides us with the so-called hit-test code in the low-order word of lParam. Do you know what is it? Could it be used in our situation to simplify coding?

Comment: `WM_MOUSEMOVE` shouldn't be involved at all. Handling `WM_SETCURSOR` will stop the cursor changing, and handling `HDN_BEGINTRACK` will prevent dragging from taking place.

Comment: As I wrote, I use WM_MOUSEMOVE not only for that - I also raise the MouseEnter/MouseLeave events for our header items from its handler. It seems, that WM_SETCURSOR is sent every time when WM_MOUSEMOVE is sent (though before it). Can we use this fact to move all this logic into the handler of WM_SETCUSOR?

Comment: I guess so? You haven't really explained what you're using WM_MOUSEMOVE for but both messages are generated as the result of mouse movement.

Comment: Currently WM_MOUSEMOVE is used to determine the header item under the mouse pointer (the hot one). This index is used to know whether this item can be resized and whether to raise MouseEnter/MouseLeave is the hot item has changed. That's all what I need.